# jQuery Ajax vs Classic ASP returning data

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Help would be appreciated.

In My ASP page I am returning this `[{'id': '123'}]`. If you view the source then that is all you will see on the page nothing else. So makes sense that when I do a get that I would be able to get the id.

My Code (which I know works because I use it to do a get on flat files containing the same data. All I want to do now is create the data on the fly):

```
    $.ajax({      
        type: "GET",      
        url: "http://localhost/GetCustNewID.asp?callback=?",      
        async: false,      
        dataType: "jsonp",  
        success: function(data){     
            $(data).each(function(){
                alert(this.id)
            });

        },
        error:function(x, e){
            if (x.status === 0){
                alert("You are offline.");
            }
            else if(x.status === 404){
                alert("404 file not found error");
            }
            else if(x.status === 500){
                alert("500 internal server error");
            }
            else if(e === 'parsererror'){
                alert("200 but can't parse json response");
            }
            else if(e === 'timeout'){
                alert("Request timed out.");
            }
            else {
                alert("Unknown AJAX error");
            }
        }

    });
```

I get a `"200 but can't parse json response"` returned. Is there something I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning (invalid) JSON, but your JS is looking for JSON-P.

A JSON-P resource would be:

```
Content-Type: application/javascript

value_of_callback_query_string_value([{"id": "123"}]);
```

As opposed to a JSON response:

```
Content-Type: application/json

[{"id": "123"}]
```

Note that in JSON, strings are delimited with **double** quotes. You should make use of [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to test your output, and use a library (some are listed near the end of the [JSON homepage](http://json.org/)) instead of trying to craft JSON by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be using "json" instead of "jsonp".

Comment: It is going to be cross-domain. Just changed it got the same error